# jQuery fadeOut => replaceWith => fadeIn

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, replacewith

I'm having a small problem with replaceWith fadeIn and fadeOut functions:

```
$('#form').fadeOut(300, function() {
    var message = 'some message';
    $(this).replaceWith($(message).fadeIn(300, function() {
        var t = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            t.fadeOut(300, function() {
                location.reload();
            });
        }, 4000);
    }));
});
```

The form fades out but nothing else happens - it removes the form but replaces it with nothing.

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

It's actually the part of the object literal - which goes like this:

```
var formObject = {
submitFadeOutReload : function(url, arr) {      
    jQuery.post(url, arr, function(data) {
        formObject.submitReplaceReload(data.message);
    }, 'json');
},
submitReplaceReload : function(message) {
    if (message !== '') { 
        formObject.objForm.fadeOut(300, function() {
            $(this).replaceWith($(message).fadeIn(300, function() {
                var t = $(this);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    t.fadeOut(300, function() {
                        $(this).replaceWith($(clone).fadeIn(300));
                    });
                }, 2000);
            }));
        });
    }
}
};
```

Comment: if you just replace it with text why don't you just do `$(this).html(message).fadeIn()`

Comment: I don't want the content of the form to be replaced - I want the form to be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - problem solved!

It appeared that the response from the $.post() call was a plain text without any wrapper (span, div) therefore it could not be used as an element. Once I've wrapped the content with the span - it all worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

No sure of everything you're trying to do but this will hopefully set you off on the right lines. A key issue in your script was $("new message"). You need to create HTML when you are adding dynamically, such as `$("<p>Something</p>")`.

```
<div id="foo">my div</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').fadeOut(300, function() {
        var $newElement = $('<div id="new div">new message</div>');
        $(this).replaceWith($newElement);
        $newElement.fadeIn(300, function() {
            document.location.reload();
        });
    });
});
```

On [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXDhu/) here.

Comment: Again - same thing as above - I don't want to replace the content of the element - I want the entire element to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks @Timbo - it doesn't seem to work unfortunately. No errors - nothing - just fades out the form and nothing else

Comment: Are you using this one it's own? It will need to be in the context of an html document - the div needs a parent element...take a look at it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/GXDhu/

Comment: Thanks Timbo - much appreciated - I've update code above - as it's a part of the object literal - if you have a look at the addition to this ticket. 'message' is received from the $.post() call and passed as parameter to the second method.